# How can I display some columns from a table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table where I store messages.
I would like to display the columns from the table.
So I need a while to make it.
But I have an error like: Notice: Undefined index: subject in ..
I hope someone can help me, thanks a lot

```
        <?php 
        //Proceso de conexión con la base de datos
        $conex = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root")
                or die("No se pudo realizar la conexion");
            mysql_select_db("carpe",$conex)
                or die("ERROR con la base de datos");

        //Iniciar Sesión
        session_start();

        //Validar si se está ingresando con sesión correctamente
        if (!$_SESSION){
        echo '<script language = javascript>
        alert("usuario no autenticado")
        self.location = "login.php"
        </script>';
        }

        $id_from = $_SESSION['id'];
        echo $id_from;
        $consulta=mysql_query("select * from messages where id_from='".$id_from."'");
        if($consulta === FALSE) {
            die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
        }

        while($filas=mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){
            echo $filas['id'];  
            $id_to=$filas['id_to'];
            $status=$filas['status'];
            $subject=$filas['subject'];
            $text=$filas['text'];
            $time=$filas['time'];
            $deleted=$filas['deleted'];

        ?>
        <label>
        <?php echo $id,$id_to,$subject,$text;?></label><br>
        <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Undefined index: subject in`

Are you 100% sure table `messages` has a field name `subject` ??? I believe case sensitive is important here.

Because that is what would cause the error.

Comment: ID
ID_FROM
ID_TO
Status
Subject
Text
Time
Deleted

these are the columns

Comment: Capital S :) its case sensitive. You should generally name all your fields in lower case to avoid these accidental mismatches :)

Comment: @user1905120 No probs if this helped please tick my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get table structure by executing this query:

```
DESCRIBE messages;
```

Alternatively, you can use [mysql_list_fields](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-fields.php) to get information about table columns.

Comment: ['subject'] != ['Subject']